# When is visa validity checked when entering US on a multistop flight?

Tags: usa, connecting-flights, h1b-visas

The H1B visa is valid starting from the 21st of September. If I take a multistop flight from New Zealand that passes through Honolulu and LAX on its way to Seattle, will my visa validity be checked at Seattle, or when I enter the US (Honolulu), or will it vary?

The stops at Honolulu and LAX are on the 20th of September local time whereas the arrival in Seattle is on the morning of the 21st.

I was just wondering because I would like to arrive as early as possible.

Comment: Honolulu-Seattle is a domestic flight...

Comment: Before embarking on your initial flight. Don't risk it, you'll be at the mercy of the check in agent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Visa validity is checked superficially at check-in. This is done by the airline to avoid penalties should it let someone fly who should not. This is not the official check though.

The official check happens at your first port of entry into the US. This will be Honolulu in your case. At that point you will enter the US and your subsequent flight will be domestic one, so you will not need to show your visa again in Seattle.

Comment: Not entirely accurate. Delta for example has a very thorough document check BEFORE the check in counter in all African countries. He wouldn't be allowed through there. I am talking from experience.

Comment: Indeed, Delta is pretty strict about it but they do not have the final word, I've seen it even from Canada. Only immigration does the real check. Unfortunately, the have the *first* check, so they could deny entry to someone that immigration would let in.

Comment: @ltai Well you nailed it. They have the first check and will deny you before you get access to immigration.

Comment: Hey guys, thanks for all the help. So as a follow up I was wondering, if I applied for the ESTA, from my understanding I would be able to get into the states early aslong as I wont be working until my H1B is valid?

Comment: Yes, because you would enter on your tourist visa. You will be able to stay as long as it remains valid and you are within the allocated stay duration. They give up to 6 months but my understanding is that it is at the discretion of the immigration officer that checks your documents on arrival.

Comment: @Itai but it is not possible to change from visa waiver status to H-1B status without leaving and reentering the US.  VWP status is for 90 days, not 6 months.